# Working with images local files in Gatsby.js

Tags: reactjs, image, rendering, gatsby

I am trying to render a headshot for each artist displayed on the page. The artist data comes from a Json file, and the images are located in images/artists/headshots. I am using the regular img tag, but for some reason nothing is displaying on the page. Any help any one can give would be greatly appreciated.

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { StaticImage } from 'gatsby-plugin-image'

import { useStyles } from './styles'

const ArtistsPage = ({ data }) => {
  const classes = useStyles()

  return (
    <section>
      <article className={classes.artistsBackground}>
        <div className={classes.heroLayoutContainer}>
          <h3 className={classes.title}>MEET THE ARTISTS</h3>

          <StaticImage
            className={classes.heroImage}
         src='../../images/artists/hero-images/hero-image-artists.jpg'
            alt='hero-image-artists'
            placeholder='blurred'
          />
        </div>
      </article>
      <article className={classes.artistsContainer}>
        <div className={classes.flexContainer}>
          {data.allArtistsJson.edges
            .map(({ node }, idx) => {
              const artist = `${node.firstName}+${node.lastName}`
                .split('+')
                .join(' ')

              return (
                <div className={classes.flexItem} key={idx}>
                  <div>
                    <img
                      src={`../../images/artists/headshots/${artist} Headshot.jpg`}
                      alt='artist-headshot'
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div className={classes.artistCardName}>
                    {`${node.firstName} ${node.lastName}`.toUpperCase()}
                  </div>
                  <div className={classes.artistCardText}>{node.city}</div>
                  <div className={classes.artistCardText}>
                    {node.currentTeam}
                  </div>
                </div>
              )
            })}
        </div>
      </article>
    </section>
  )
}

export default ArtistsPage
```

My image files are set up as:
FirstName LastName Headshots.jpg

Comment: have you read gatsby docs on images? https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/working-with-images/

Comment: @diedu Yes, I have been going over the docs for the last week and nothing I have done has worked, which is why I asked for help here.

Comment: Do you get any errors on the node console or browser console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much research and the nice people on Gatsby discord I found the answer to be… in a scenario like this I needed to add require().default.
Ex:
<img
src={require(`../../images/artists/headshots/${artist} Headshot.jpg`).default}
alt='artist-headshot'
/>

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue may comes from the white spaces in the naming. Your code looks good at first sight so try renaming your images with underscore or in camelCase:

```
   <img
      src={`../../images/artists/headshots/${artist}_Headshot.jpg`}
      alt='artist-headshot'
    />
```